# Changing logo and main menu colour on specific page

Tags: css

I want to change the logo and main menu in the header on this page only:

https://www.maisondefemmes.com/galentines-day/​​

I've tried updating the css and only managed to edit the search and cart colours.

I've tried using both `content` and `background-image`, as well as using `logoimg bg--dark` rather than `#logo` but to no avail.

```
.page-id-3055 #logo {
    content: url(https://www.maisondefemmes.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/mdf-retina-logo-red.png) !important;
}
```

I want the logo and main menu to be `#b50c3f` but they don't budge. I've managed to change Search and Cart.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  You cannot just provide links to your site: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: there is no `.page-id-3055 #logo` on the page - there is `.page-id-3055 .header .logolink .logoimg` -- which would work

Comment: @pete I did provide code: 

.page-id-3055 #logo { content: url(https://www.maisondefemmes.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/mdf-retina-logo-red.png) !important; }

Comment: Yes but it doesn't replicate your error - please see [mcve] (by the way it wasn't me that downvoted) - without enough code to replicate the error in the question itself, your question is actually off topic for SO: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @Stender thank you - .logoimg worked and links back to my homepage now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And this is why your question is off topic - you will now fix the page and future visitors will no longer be able to see what the actual error is and therefore this question will be of no use to anyone who may have a similar problem (that is why you need to put enough code in the question to replicate the issue)

Comment: @pete ok - so I should just leave an error on my page??  My question is now off-topic because the problem's fixed?

Comment: For users with a similar issue: the error was that I used #logo instead of .logoimg

Comment: Your question is off topic because you don't have any code in your question that shows what the issue is - you had a link to your site showing us that you had an error, but now you've fix, it you have no error and there is not enough code in the actual question to be able to see any error - just a line of css that by itself will work.  Anyway just read the links and you will understand why your question is off topic

Comment: @Jess no problem - glad to help! But as Pete is saying, this question sadly does not benefit anyone who comes here in the future. It is not because it has been answered. The reason is, that the problem was a simple typo. People in here are ruthless against that sort of thing, because bloat makes it harder, for future users, to find the answers they are looking for c",)

Comment: @Jess - So not that you have received the help needed, I would suggest to simply close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Logo is a html img tag and you can't change it that way. The content attribute only works for pseudo elements. One solution would be the following:

```
.page-id-3055 .logolink > img {
     display: none;
}
.page-id-3055 .logolink:before {
     display: inline-bloc;
     content: url(https://www.maisondefemmes.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/mdf-retina-logo-red.png) !important;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect url with jquery and then change logo and menu by jquery css

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("galentines-day") > -1) {
   // do something
}
```